# Ngxin start chrome webdriver

Tags: selenium, nginx, selenium-webdriver

I have a rails website.

On a controller. I have an action that run a selenium web driver to imitate a human like create or order products from a site by click click....

The issue is. When I run it by `rails s` it works. But when I deployed and running with nginx. It doesn't work.

Error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.)
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I guess reason is nginx cannot start browser, but don't know how to config.

I have to run with browser on GUI because I need this option `disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` and that doesn't work with `--headless`

Any one can give me advice

Comment: it usually means your chrome.exe and chromedriver are nto compatible , make sure the versions are right in the nginx server

Comment: But it works if I run from local with rails s.